# The developer name string should be modified

Tags: bug, status-declined, ios-app

When I first launch the App I am presented with a confirmation dialog.  The dialog specifies the name of the developer as "iPhone Distribution: Stack Exchange Inc."

See screen shot (no jokes about my 10K unread email please).

A better name for the Developer string would be simply "Stack Exchange"  or possibly "Stack Exchange, Inc."

Not really a bug but... not really right either.

[image: Confirmation Dialog]

Comment: Man look at all those.......... apps you need to upgrade.

Comment: "You've got mail"

Comment: Mint scares me. You are literally giving away your username and passwords to various online banking accounts to them.

Comment: Bro, forget the bug reports, clean out that email.  Seriously, at least create some rules and sort that stuff into folders.  Man.

Comment: A downvote on this?  I am baffled... "does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not helpful"‽  Does the downvoter care to state a reason?

Comment: I don't think this is a compelling reason to downvote, but maybe it was because that menu is exclusive to alpha testing, and won't exist in release, thus not worth fixing?

Comment: @mhlester Thanks.  That could be. I submitted this report thinking that string would be the developer name in iTunes as well, but perhaps the ad-hoc developer name is not tied to the iTunes developer name.

Comment: Needs some red freehand circles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the kind of thing that we'll get cleaned up when we're about to go to the apple store.  Thanks for the report, but nothing to worry about right now.

Comment: I don't think [status-declined] is the right tag for this (even though I know you mean status-declined as not applicable to prerelease branch).

Comment: Do you think [meta-tag:status-deferred] then?